# R ggsn scalebar distorted in m projection

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, gis

I seem not to be able to create a proper scale bar with EPSG:31287. 
The documentation of scalebar() states, that if the option dd2km = FALSE, no model is required. Still it is not possible to run without that option.

WGS84 works, but the display of the whole map is a bit distorted, thus I would prefer the other CRS. See code below. Any hints would be appreciated.

```
library(maps)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsn)

aust <- map("world","austria",fill=TRUE,plot=FALSE) # import map
p4s <- CRS("+init=epsg:31287") # define target CRS
wgs84 <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # define origin CRS

ausp <- map2SpatialPolygons(aust,IDs="Austria",wgs84) # convert map to sppoly
ausp2 <- spTransform(ausp, p4s) # transform to target CRS
ausp3 <- fortify(ausp2, region = "name") # convert to df; EPSG:31287
ausp4 <- fortify(ausp, region = "name") # convert to df; WGS84

# Plot function
# EPSG:31287 - ScaleBar won't work! 
x11(width=12,height=7)
ggplot(ausp3,aes(x=long, y=lat))+
  geom_polygon(fill="white")+ # fine
  coord_equal()+ # fine
  geom_path()+ # fine
  scalebar(ausp3, dist = 1000,dd2km = FALSE, model = 'WGS84')+ # compressed!
  north(ausp3, location ="bottomleft", symbol = 12) # fine

# WGS84
x11(width=12,height=7)
ggplot(ausp4,aes(x=long, y=lat))+
  geom_polygon(fill="white")+ # fine
  coord_equal()+ # fine
  geom_path()+ # fine
  scalebar(ausp4, dist = 50,dd2km = TRUE, model = 'WGS84')+ # fine!
  north(ausp4, location ="bottomleft", symbol = 12) # fine
```

Comment: Use the version at devtools::install_github('oswaldosantos/ggsn') which has this bug fixed

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!